# Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Error starting at line : 15 in command -

```
CREATE TABLE USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.EmployeePhone
(
    EmployeeID int,
    EmployeePhone varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Primary key (EmployeeID),
    EmployeeID int REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID) on DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Error:

> ORA-00957: duplicate column name
>   00957. 00000 -  "duplicate column name"
>
> *Cause:
>   *Action:

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
CREATE TABLE USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.EmployeePhone (
    EmployeeID int primary key references Employee(EmployeeID) on DELETE NO ACTION,
    EmployeePhone varchar(30) NOT NULL
);
```

But why not just store `EmployeePhone` in `Employee`?

Answer (score 0):

Should:

```
EmployeeID int REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID) on DELETE NO ACTION)
```

be,

```
FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID) on DELETE NO ACTION)
```

?